# Step counter using Google-Fit sensors API

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-fit

I have been toying with Xamarin and Google Fit for some time and I'm trying to make a simple step counter app. I cannot get the listener to work. As I understand it, the `OnDataPointListener`'s `OnDataPoint()` method will be called each time a step is taken. With my code I don't see anything happening. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code I am using (shortened to include only the relevant parts)

**MainActivity.cs**

```
GoogleApiClient mClient;
OnDataPointListener _mListener;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        authInProgress = bundle.GetBoolean(AUTH_PENDING);
    }
    _viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.container);
    _viewPager.Adapter = new FragmentAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
    BuildFitnessClient();
}
```

**BuildFitnessClient**

```
void BuildFitnessClient()
{
    var clientConnectionCallback = new ClientConnectionCallback();
    clientConnectionCallback.OnConnectedImpl = async () => await FindFitnessDataSources();
    mClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .AddApi(FitnessClass.SENSORS_API)
        .AddScope(FitnessClass.ScopeActivityReadWrite)
        .AddScope(FitnessClass.ScopeBodyReadWrite)
        .AddScope(FitnessClass.ScopeLocationRead)
        .AddConnectionCallbacks(clientConnectionCallback)
        .AddOnConnectionFailedListener((ConnectionResult result) =>
        {
            if (!result.HasResolution)
            {
                // Show the localized error dialog
#pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.GetErrorDialog(result.ErrorCode, this, 0).Show();
#pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
                return;
            }
            if (!authInProgress)
            {
                try
                {
                    authInProgress = true;
                    result.StartResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_OAUTH);
                }
                catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
                {
                }
            }
        }).Build();
}

private async Task FindFitnessDataSources()
{

    var dataSourcesResult = await FitnessClass.SensorsApi.FindDataSourcesAsync(mClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
        .SetDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TypeDerived)
        .SetDataTypes(DataType.TypeStepCountDelta)
        .Build());

    foreach (DataSource dataSource in dataSourcesResult.DataSources)
    {
        if (_mListener == null)
        {
            await RegisterFitnessDataListener(dataSource, dataSource.DataType);
        }
    }
}

private async Task RegisterFitnessDataListener(DataSource dataSource, DataType dataType)
{
    var status = await FitnessClass.SensorsApi.AddAsync(mClient, new SensorRequest.Builder()
         .SetDataSource(dataSource) // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
         .SetDataType(dataType) // Can't be omitted.
         .SetSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.Seconds)
         .Build(), _mListener);
    if (status.IsSuccess)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Listener connected", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

**ClientConnectionCallback.cs**

```
internal class ClientConnectionCallback : Java.Lang.Object, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks
{
    public Action OnConnectedImpl { get; set; }

    public void OnConnected(Android.OS.Bundle connectionHint)
    {
        OnConnectedImpl();
    }

    public void OnConnectionSuspended(int cause)
    {
        if (cause == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CauseNetworkLost)
        {
            Log.Info("Health365", "Connection lost.  Cause: Network Lost.");
        }
        else if (cause == GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.CauseServiceDisconnected)
        {
            Log.Info("Health365", "Connection lost. Reason: Service Disconnected");
        }
    }
}
```

**IOnDataPointListener**

```
public class OnDataPointListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnDataPointListener, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void OnDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint)
    {
        foreach (var field in dataPoint.DataType.Fields)
        {
            Value val = dataPoint.GetValue(field);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question/issue? Have you narrowed the problem at all?

Comment: The `OnDataPointListener`'s `OnDataPoint()` method will be called each time a step is taken. With the above code i don't see anything happening. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does this line get executed at all? `Toast.MakeText(this, "Listener connected", ToastLength.Short).Show();` Please say what you've already tried and what you think the problem might be.

Comment: Yes i see the toast message. I am actually not sure what the problem is because i see no errors. Just that nothing happens. May be someone can cook up a sample that counts steps which i can then verify against mine

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know C#. Your `OnDataPoint` isn't called at all? Are you sure it's not just that `foreach (var field in dataPoint.DataType.Fields)` hits nothing?

Comment: Haha. Yes I am sure.